# Visual Studio 2010 Javascript Code Snippets: Based on function parameters

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, code-snippets

What I'm looking to do is add vsdoc info to my javascript using snippets.  I'd like to be able to select below a javascript function declaration, call my snippet, and the snippet would create the summary tag and 1 param tag for each parameter in the function.  I'd also like a unicorn.

Maybe this is just crazy for code snippets, so if you have a better idea (macros/extension) let me know.

---

Edit: adding a code sample to explain better.

Say I have this javascript:

```
function myfunc(param1, param2) {
   ... // clicking here
   do stuff
   ...
}
```

What I'm hoping to do is put my cursor on the line with 'click here' and call a code snippet that will turn the above javascript code into this:

```
function myfunc(param1, param2) {
   /// <summary></summary>
   /// <param name="param1" type=""></param>
   /// <param name="param2" type=""></param>
   ...
   do stuff
   ...
}
```

The snippet would set me up with a cursor in the summary tag, and tabbing would jump to each param type and text area.  Hopefully this helps explain things better.